# Write splunk query to fetch the number of working days greater than zero

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to write a splunk query where I need to fetch the user details with the number of working days if it is greater than zero. For example I have the below data

```
I, [2022-01-04T01:32:10.165065 #21461]  INFO -- : fetched user details for user_id: 5612 with working_days: 0

I, [2021-01-04T01:32:10.165065 #21461]  INFO -- : fetched user details for user_id: 5619 with working_days: 10

I, [2021-02-04T01:28:10.165065 #21461]  INFO -- : fetched user details for user_id: 8901 with working_days: 0

I, [2021-03-04T01:18:10.165065 #21461]  INFO -- : fetched user details for user_id: 306561 with working_days: 35
```

I need to fetch user_id along with working_days. The only condition is working days more than 0

```
fetched user details for user_id: 5619 with working_days: 10
fetched user details for user_id: 306561 with working_days: 35
```

The below query is not giving the correct result. Any help is appreciated

```
"fetched user details for user_id: " 
| rex field=_raw "fetched user details for user_id:(?<user_id>.*) with working_days:(?<working_days>.*)" 
| table user_id,working_days
```

Update 1

I have tried following ways but none of it works

```
"fetched user details for user_id: " 
| rex field=_raw "fetched user details for user_id:(?<user_id>.\d+) with working_days:(?<working_days>.\d+)" 
| where working_days > 0 | table user_id,working_days

"fetched user details for user_id: " 
| rex field=_raw "fetched user details for user_id:(?<user_id>.\d+) with working_days:(?<working_days>.\d+)" 
| where 'working_days' > 0 | table user_id,working_days

"fetched user details for user_id: " 
| rex field=_raw "fetched user details for user_id:(?<user_id>.\d+) with working_days:(?<working_days>.\d+)" 
| where working_days > '0' | table user_id,working_days

"fetched user details for user_id: " 
| rex field=_raw "fetched user details for user_id:(?<user_id>.\d+) with working_days:(?<working_days>.\d+)" 
| where "working_days" > '0' | table user_id,working_days

"fetched user details for user_id: " 
| rex field=_raw "fetched user details for user_id:(?<user_id>.\d+) with working_days:(?<working_days>.\d+)" 
| where not working_days == 0 | table user_id,working_days
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `where` or `search` command to filter results.

```
"fetched user details for user_id: " 
| rex field=_raw " user_id:(?<user_id>\d+) with working_days:(?<working_days>\d+)" 
| search working_days > 0
| table user_id,working_days
```

Comment: I have tried with where clause but it doesn't work

Comment: What are we supposed to do with "it doesn't work"?  Please share the full query you're running and describe or post the results.  Then we can suggest something else to try.  Sometimes `| search working_days > 0` has better results than `where`.

Comment: | search working_days > 0 worked for me. Thanks you can update the existing answer